# asp.net 6 EF using MySql Database not working

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webapi, .net-6.0

I am trying to connect my Web API build in asp.net 6 with MySql and I am having a lot of trouble

My Service looks like this

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TicketApiContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySQL("CONNECTION_STRING"));
```

and my Database Context like this.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace VelocityNetAPI.Data
{
    public class TicketApiContext : DbContext
    {
        public TicketApiContext(DbContextOptions<TicketApiContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<VelocityNetAPI.Models.Client> Client { get; set; }

        public DbSet<VelocityNetAPI.Models.Job> Job { get; set; }

        public DbSet<VelocityNetAPI.Models.User> User { get; set; }

        public DbSet<VelocityNetAPI.Models.Dev> Dev { get; set; }

        public DbSet<VelocityNetAPI.Models.FinishedJobs> FinishedJobs { get; set; }
        

    }
}
```

when I run add-migration initial I get an error

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSourceDependencies' while attempting to activate 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLTypeMappingSource'.
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.[image: Here is my Nuget packages]

Please help I am completely lost

Cheers All

Comment: Are all the dependencies installed too? You don't need SQLServer package, unless you're targeting both dbs. Have you tried using v5  instead of v6? e.g. questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224907/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-diagnostics-idi

Comment: Sql Server is not used as the service is configured to mysql. I havent tried going from MySql 6 to 5 ill do that now

Comment: Try to use `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` package - it is much widely used (19M downloads vs 737K of Oracle package)

Comment: I have found a repos with the use of pomelo so I will try that soon. cheers for the help lads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after tweaking I have the solution.
Using the pomelo package and this line.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TicketAPIContext>(options =>
  options.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TicketApiContextMySql"), new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 22))));
```

Hope this helps devs

Answer (score 2):

I did an investigation into this here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106592

```
public class MysqlEntityFrameworkDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddEntityFrameworkMySQL();
        new EntityFrameworkRelationalDesignServicesBuilder(serviceCollection)
            .TryAddCoreServices();
    }
}
```

Should be a workaround to it. It seems that in .NET6, `TryAddCoreServices()` was introduced but not implemented in `Mysql.EntityFrameworkCore`

I've not heard much on if anybody has had any issue with this, but it worked for me.

Comment: I have added this class to data layer csproj which includes dbcontext and then Add-Migration worked successfully and added the migration folder and classes. Thx. (I use the latest EFCore version)