# ASP.NET 6 Scaffolding dbcontext MySQL Error: Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to generate a context/model for MVC based on an existing MySQL database. Previously generated one for SQL in the same project, which worked. I am assuming that the error comes from being unable to convert the types. How could I resolve this error? If not, and I have to create the model file manually, would it implicitly convert the MySQL types to the C# types I put?

**Scaffold Command:**

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings:FailLogs MySql.EntityFrameworkCore --table Scan_Volume_Fail_Logs`

**Error Log:**

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IDiagnosticsLogger`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbLoggerCategory+Scaffolding]' while attempting to activate 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String ootations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputD   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluarlize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IDiagnosticsLogger`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbLoggerCategory+Scaffolding]' while attempting to activate 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.MySQLDatabaseModelFactory'.
```

**Some of MySQL Types Used:**

[image: MySQL Types]

Comment: Check this following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224907/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-diagnostics-idi

Comment: Solution worked, changed to `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`. Thanks